# Mounting /tmp as tmpfs on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab, tmpfs

I'd like to mount `/tmp` without fstab entry using `tmp.mount`

However on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, it doesn't seem to work.

```
user@user-x1:~$ systemctl status tmp.mount 
Unit tmp.mount could not be found.
user@user-x1:~$ sudo systemctl enable tmp.mount 
Failed to enable unit: Unit file tmp.mount does not exist.
user@user-x1:~$ sudo systemctl cat tmp.mount 
No files found for tmp.mount.
user@user-x1:~$ cat /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount 
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Temporary Directory (/tmp)
Documentation=https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES
Documentation=man:file-hierarchy(7)
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/tmp
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
After=swap.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/tmp
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
user@user-x1:~$
```

What's happening? Why does systemd say unit could not be found even though bash auto tabbing fills up `tmp.mount` and what's the simplest way to enable this `tmpfs` without any config?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

tmp.mount is not enabled by default.
Just copy and enable it

```bsh
sudo cp -v /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/ 
sudo systemctl enable tmp.mount
```

Comment: Thanks @ExploitFate!

Comment: Maybe symlink (`ln -s`) would be better than copy (`cp`). But it's just a detail :)

Answer (score 11):

Note that `systemctl enable` accept absolute paths to unit files. (See [systemctl man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html)) So there's no need to copy it manually.

I have tested on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount → /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount.
```

Comment: Interesting. And will `systemd` deal with all the required configuration details, e.g. properly formatting the in-memory `/tmp` and so forth (or whatever the initialisation it requires)? All I see on Ubuntu 22.04 is that it is expected to eat up 50% of all available memory, which seems to me to be overkill...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn "formatting" a tmpfs makes no sense, it's a virtual filesystem so the kernel just provides you with a clean one when asked. `tmpfs` allowing use of up to 50% of RAM is the default, but that doesn't mean that 50% of RAM is immediately marked as used when a tmpfs is mounted.