# Is there a way to relocate all data traffic to/from /tmp to /dev/shm/tmp?

Tags: ram, tmp, shm

Is there a way to relocate all data traffic to/from `/tmp` to `/dev/shm/tmp`? The performance of the RAM is always faster than the SSD. Furthermore, `/tmp` is used to store short-term temporary files. For a system with large-capacity RAM, the proposition of using the RAM to host `/tmp` seems attractive to do.

Comment: @muru Yes and thanks. I ran the answer by [RichardYu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1416156/541417), i.e. `$ sudo systemctl enable /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount` and restarted the system. The command `df`  confirmed that `tmpfs` is mounted on `/tmp`.